# Changing part of an Excel formula based on another cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have an excel formula running in cell `C4` with the below formula.

It takes info from cell `V5` on the tab called `06-01-20` from a workbook called `file1.xlsm` located in `C:\Excel\` on my computer.

```
='C:\Excel\[file1.xlsm]06-01-20'!V5
```

I want to change the `06-01-20` part of the formula to the value of cell `C2` in my workbook (not the `file1.xlsm` workbook, the workbook containing the formula above.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at `INDIRECT`,  though the source workbook needs to be open.

Comment: If your goal is to use VBA to replace it make sure you [edit] your question and show the code and what you already have tried. Note that the `file1.xlsm` needs to be opened in Excel in order to change the formula and make it work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - note the VB approach does not necessarily require fie1.xslm to be open at the same time - tested/tried in my soln below...

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot(s) refer -

**Setup**

Assume 'other' workbook (file1.xlsm) has two sheets:

1. 06-01-02 (cell v5: 'Original ref in 06-01-02') - per C1 of 'active workbook'
2. 06-01-30 (cell v5: 'New ref in 06-01-30') - per C2 of 'active workbook'

Formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(C4),C1,C2),"=","")
```

[image: Function to update sheet name]

---

**1) Indirect formula approach**

*Only works if other workbook (file1.xlsm) is open....*

```
=INDIRECT(D4,1)
```

[image: function for indirect forumla approach]

---

**2) VBA approach**

*works whether other workbook open / closed, but requires interim 'step' (can be combined with first function if no indirect approach desired)*

Insert this function:

```
="="&D4
```

[image: Interim step for VB]

VB code to retrieve value from different sheet (06-01-30):

```
Range("G5").Value = Range("E4").Value
```

[image: VBA output in cell G5 (while file1.xlsm closed)]

---

Notes:

- First function can be amended to change workbook and cell references too (not just sheet name as done here)
- Notice in final screenshot how indirect formula (cell G4) returns `#REF!` whilst VB approach (G5) operates just fine - this is because the VB code was run whilst file1.xlsm was closed

---